# Task.StartNew Parallel.ForEach doesn't await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have this code:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => Parallel.ForEach(
        urls,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 },
        async url =>
        {
           Uri uri = new Uri(url);
           string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

           using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
           using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
           using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
           {
               // ... Read the string.
               using (var fileStream = new FileStream(config.M_F_P + filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
               {
                   await content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
               }
           }
        }));

MessageBox.Show("Completed");
```

It is supposed to process a list of more than 800 elements but it doesn't wait for the download and filewrite to be finished.
In fact he starts downloading and writing, shows the message and then in background keep downloading...
I need to download a lot of files in parallels and async but i have to wait for all of them to be downloading. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` doesn't work with async. It expects an `Action` but in order to await the async method it needs to get a `Func<Task>`.

You can use TPL Dataflow's `ActionBlock` that was build with async in mind instead. You give it a delegate (async or not) to perform on each item. You configure the block's parallelism (and bounded capacity if necessary). And you post your items into it:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<string>(async url => 
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
       // ... Read the string.
       using (var fileStream = new FileStream(config.M_F_P + filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
       {
           await content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
       }
    }
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 } );

foreach (var url in urls)
{
    block.Post(url);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
// done
```

Comment: It says ActionBlock doesn't exist in this namespace. If i try to import it with using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow it says Dataflow doesn't exist. What can i do?

Comment: @giogiowefj It's a nuget, not a part of the "traditional" .net framework. You can get it here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/

Comment: Ok now it runs but it still doesn't wait for everything to be completed

Comment: @giogiowefj You need to wait for the block to complete using its `Completion` property as you can see in my answer.

Comment: Oh, didn't see it, did you edit the answer? With that it just works fine! Thank you so much! But i still can't understand why can't i use my code. I've never seen ActionBlock in my life, where can i study it?

Comment: @giogiowefj Yes, I did. Several times actually. You can't use `Parallel.Foreach` as it predates async-await so it expects a delegate that returns a void. In order to await an async method it needs to return a `Task`. You can see that `ActionBlock` accepts both `Action<T>` for synchronous operations and `Func<T>` for async ones. You can read more about it on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @i3arnon I've read that [`new`'ing up a new `HttpClient` isn't good practice](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), each time. So maybe that should be moved out of the asynchronous Action?

Comment: @Pure.Krome it's just a copy of OP's action... but yes, the creation can be extracted out.